# Deactivate tortoise SVN for certain local folders

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a network mounted drive and as a result if I right click anywhere it hangs for awhile. this is because TortoiseSVN is trying to read the local .svn repo. Is there a way that I can prevent this from ever happening for certain local repos? Say perhaps I can have TortoiseSVN not open for files under the W:\ drive?

The icon overlays are already turned off (by default) because W:\ is a network drive. But when I right click anywhere I can see a large file transfer occur for the .svn folder everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this was easy to find via the settings. I just assumed it wasn't there initially but for such an established program it makes sense that this would already be a feature:

[image: Ignore paths]